# Can't open deploy.prototxt.txt

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, face-detection

I've been agonizing over the problem for a long time. downloaded zip archive from github. I tried many times and it didn't work out.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests
import os

print(os.listdir(r"C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/face-detection-with-OpenCV-and-DNN-master/"))
prototxt_path = r"C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/face-detection-with-OpenCV-and-DNN-master/deploy.prototxt.txt"
caffemodel_path = r"C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/face-detection-with-OpenCV-and-DNN-master/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt_path, caffemodel_path)

# Set up the DroidCam Source 3 camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://---.---.--.-:----/mjpegfeed")

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt_path, caffemodel_path)
```

outputs this error.

```
File "C:\Users\Алекс\Desktop\camera.py", line 9, in <module>
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt_path, caffemodel_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1126: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/face-detection-with-OpenCV-and-DNN-master/deploy.prototxt.txt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'
```

help me please

many times, I deleted the extension .txt, tried to find using os.path.join() function and no result, path is completely correct.

Comment: wait a second..

Comment: Windows sometimes hides the extensions of known files. Are you sure in "C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/face-detection-with-OpenCV-and-DNN-master/" you have a file named exactly "deploy.prototxt.txt"?

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the extension. I'm completely sure

Comment: The error is telling you that it cannot open that file. Can you try making a simple program that does `with open("your/path/to/the/file.txt", 'r') as f: print(f.readlines())` and see if the proram prints the content of that file?

Comment: how do I write if there are a lot of characters?

Comment: 36.000 characters

Comment: It's probably the Cyrillic in the username (Алекс). Try a path that contains only plain ASCII characters.